# Empty model properties when posting to a controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to post to a controller action and have the model be populated correctly, but all I get is an empty model with both of its properties set to null.

Here's the parameter model:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    public string UserName;
    public string Password;
}
```

Here is the action:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    // model.UserName and model.Password are null for some reason
}
```

Here's the route config:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "AuthApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/login",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "ApiAccount",
        action = "login"
    }
);
```

Here's the request:

```
POST /api/login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:51444
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

UserName=me&Password=testfake
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding get/set to view model:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your controller action is expecting either of the following two cases.

1. A POST to this URL with an empty body:

   ```
   /api/login?UserName=me&Password=testfake
   ```
2. A POST to `/api/login` with this body:

   ```
   {
       "UserName": "me",
       "Password": "testfake"
   }
   ```